# How to read logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I've just recently started android development, and part of my code is redirecting me to the main activity rather than the activity it is meant to, after looking at the logcat, I've tried to find out what it means to no avail, is there anyone that understands the following?

> E/audit: type=1400 audit(1581015631.627:66063): avc:  denied  { write
>   } for  pid=5075 comm="ng.android.lool"
>   name="com.samsung.android.lool-iu7CVBUt_Wz2aQFIX8cssg==" dev="dm-1"
>   ino=8401 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0
>   tcontext=u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
>   SEPF_SM-N950F_9_0012 audit_filtered

Comment: You should set the filter to display only message that belong to your app.This line does not seem to belong to your app. You can also place `Log.d(...)` i your code. But more effective is to put break-points into the code and start the app in debug mode. When the break-point hits the app stops and you can inspect the variables.

Comment: Hey, this was with the filter of com.example..., and it was the only line to come up when the error happened - which is why I'm so confused

Comment: Add your own logs to understand what is happening. Also show us the code here that you expect to do the navigation